# Printout active sheet when cell different cells changing

Tags: vba, excel

Please find the Snapshot attached herewith, I have problem with print sheet.

[image]

I have account numbers from 1 to 60, i need to print 2 invoices in a single page.
so cell values 1 and 2 in one page, 2 and 3 in second page and so on.

I need to print 60 invoices in 30 pages.

I facing problem that my program prints when only one cell values changes.

Please find my program.

```
Sub Button3_Click()
    Dim i As Integer
     Dim VList As Variant 
    VList = Array("1", "2", "3", "4", "5")
    For i = LBound(VList) To UBound(VList)
    Range("F52") = VList(i) 'first cell value
       Next
   Range("F84") = VList(i)  'second cell value

  Next
  ActiveSheet.PrintOut
End Sub
```

Comment: You have only one `For` and two `Next`. `For` and `Next` need to be balanced. Just increment i by 2 in the `For`, and use VList(i) and VList(i+1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have only one `For` and two `Next`. `For` and `Next` need to be balanced. Just increment i by 2 in the `For`, and use `VList(i)` and `VList(i+1)`.

```
Sub Button3_Click()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim VList As Variant 
    VList = Array("1", "2", "3", "4", "5")
    For i = LBound(VList) To UBound(VList) Step 2
        Range("F52") = VList(i)   'first cell value
        Range("F84") = VList(i+1) 'second cell value
    Next
    ActiveSheet.PrintOut
End Sub
```

You migth want to add some verifications in case of odd number of invoice.

Answer (score 0):

If this is the full code , I'm not sure why you are using array !

Please try this code.

```
    Sub Button3_Click()
    Dim i As Integer

    For i = 1 To 60 Step 2

        Select Case i
        Case 7, 21, 34, 49
        Case Else
            Range("F52") = i    'first cell value if i=6
            Range("F84") = i + 1    'second cell value i+1 = 7 So code fails to check
        End Select
    Next
    ActiveSheet.PrintOut
    End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you Imran for your code, but I would like skip some numbers from 1 to 60, example in between 1 to 60,  "7" "21" "34" and "49" not exist. So i used array to set particular number. Can you please help me.